# Name sc is not defined

Tags: pyspark

I am just trying to execute `sc.version` inside pyspark shell however getting an error as `sc` not defined.

```
>>> sc.version()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
```

If i run `SparkContext.getOrCreate()`

```
>>> SparkContext.getOrCreate()
<pyspark.context.SparkContext object at 0x7f206aa8cfd0>
```

I am not getting even the output of sc.version(). What is the problem?

Comment: `sc = SparkContext.getOrCreate()`

Answer (score 1):

A few things:

1. Inside the pyspark shell you automatically only have access to the spark session (which can be referenced by "spark").
2. To get the sparkcontext, you can get it from the spark session by `sc = spark.sparkContext`. Or using the `getOrCreate()` method as mentioned by @Smurphy0000 in the comments
3. Version is an attribute of the spark context. To get the version from sparkcontext (`sc` in this case), `version = sc.version`. Version can also be extracted from the session directly as `version = spark.version`

Comment: >>> version = spark.version
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'spark' is not defined
>>> version = sc.version
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'sc' is not defined
>>> sc = spark.sparkContext
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'spark' is not defined, No luck with these commands

Comment: can you post the the starting the messages when you start the pyspark shell? You should get something like this as the last few lines : \Using Python version 3.8.2 (default, Jul 16 2020 14:00:26)
SparkSession available as 'spark'.

Comment: Also you did you iniitalize sc as `sc = spark.sparkContext`?